# Installing pycairo on Python 3

Tags: 12.04, python

I'm trying to install `pycairo`, but my symlink is sending it to python 2, though it requires 3. How do I get around this error?

```
# ./waf build
  ./options()
The project was not configured: run "waf configure" first!
root@Archimedes:/home/archimedes/Downloads/pycairo-1.10.0# ./waf configure
  ./options()
Setting top to                           : /home/archimedes/Downloads/pycairo-1.10.0 
Setting out to                           : /home/archimedes/Downloads/pycairo-1.10.0/build_directory 
  ./configure()
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok 
Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python 
Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 3, 'final', 0) 
The python version is too old, expecting (3, 1, 0)
(complete log in /home/archimedes/Downloads/pycairo-1.10.0/build_directory/config.log)
```

Is there a way to send it to `/usr/bin/python3` instead of `/usr/bin/python` (the symlink) when it checks for python? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `$PYTHON` to the path of the binary you want to use, for example

```
export PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
./waf configure
```